# How to Print to Query Code [PDO]

Tags: php, debugging, pdo

```
try {
     $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $root, $root_password);
     $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (test1, test1, test1)") 

     or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true));

     } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
     }
```

I used to print it on the screen SQL query: `$sth->debugDumpParams();` but I get Internal 500 error

How can I print the query?

Comment: Read logs and find the cause of 500 error.

Comment: `$sth` does not seem to exist, is that really what you are using? And where?

Comment: Hello again @jeroen , I updated the question

Comment: Please don't rewrite code as it invalidates answers provided to original. Your edit should be a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost every line of this code snippet is wrong. There is no `$sth` to get debugDumpParams from for starter. Not to mention the way you are running a query which is totally wrong.

Here is how it should be

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $root, $root_password);
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(['test1', 'test1', 'test1'])
```

now you can use whatever method to echo your query, be it debugDumpParams or simply echo $sql, but neither would be of much help because it will print you exactly the same what you have in your script already:

```
INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Yet I suppose you need not a query but the error message, the code above will supply you with - just run it.

Note that you should avoid either `die()` or `try` statements in this code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your response is very different therefore I updated the question

Comment: For the multi-query you were executing via exec() there is no way to get it from PDO. However, you can always assign it to a PHP variable and echo this variable out. But still you need not a query but an error message which is pretty obvious.

Comment: I understand Thank you